# ParseConfig vs ParseQuery - Which is faster/better?

Tags: parse-platform

So i'm essentially using a column in my parse server db as a configuration for my app.  I now realize parse has a config feature specifically for this.

> My question is which is faster/better to use and why? Hitting a query every single time i want to check, or check the parse config.  Isn't checking the config variable just another query?

If anyone can provide proper/better/ or any documentation...

Answer (score 0):

**ParseConfig** is faster because it store the config in the cache while ParseQuery will retrieve it from the DB. But you cannot use ParseConfig for every query operation but only to get things that are relevant to all of your users like: "Message of the day" and more. 
Another very cool thing about ParseConfig is that if you don't have network connectivity it will fallback automatically to the client cache.